# Unity3D - How to make partially selected EditorGUI.Toggle?

Tags: unity

I have nested group of toggles created with EditorGUILayout.ToggleLeft().

I want to change state of the parent toggle to partial check if child toggles have mixed states, like here:

[image: example]

But [EditorGUILayout.ToggleLeft](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.ToggleLeft.html) value is a boolean value, so how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use [EditorGUI.showMixedValue](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI-showMixedValue.html)